# How to calculate $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \frac {n-3}{n}\right) ^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

How to calculate $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \dfrac {n-3}{n}\right) ^{n}$, The answer is $e^{-3}$, I'm comfusing with the process...

Comment: Typically when dealing with indeterminate forms like $1^\infty$, you take the natural log (to get the exponent down) and calculate the limit of that. Then exponentiate with $e$ to get your final answer.

Comment: *Hint:* For all real $a$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac an \right)^n = e^a$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\right).$$
Besides, one has: $$\ln\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)=-\frac{3}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
Hence, one has: $$n\ln\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}-3.$$
Since $\exp$ is continuous at $-3$, one has: $$\exp\left(n\ln\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}e^{-3}.$$
Finally, one has: $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^n=e^{-3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Just rewrite
$$
\frac{n-3}{n} = 1-\frac{3}{n}.
$$
Then multiply and divide the exponent by $3$...

Answer (score 0):

> $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \dfrac {n-3}{n}\right) ^{n}$$

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\exp\left( n\ln \bigg(\dfrac {n-3}{n}\bigg)\right) $$

$$\exp\bigg(\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \dfrac {\ln(\frac{n-3}{n})}{1/n}\right) \bigg)$$

Lhopital:

$$=\exp\bigg( \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }-\frac{3n}{n-3}\bigg)$$

$$\boxed{\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{e^3}}}$$